# What parts of speech are the verbs "[She] was lying …, listening to … reading a story" and their function?

Tags: parts-of-speech, participles

> Allice was lying under a tree listening to his sister reading a story.

What is the parts of speech of *lying, listening* and *reading* and their function?

Comment: I've made a basic fix to your question, which was blank.  Can you now demonstrate some prior effort.  What is the difficulty here?

Comment: (Female) Alice: "**her** *brother*"// (Male) Alan: "**his** *brother*"

Comment: They are all verbs, functioning as predicators (heads) of the clauses "**lying** under a tree" /  "**listening** to his sister**" / "**reading** a story".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Allice was* **[** *lying under a tree* **]** **[** *listening to his sister* [*reading a story*]**]**.

The simple answer is that "lying", "listening" and "reading" belong to the category (part of speech) **verb** (sub-type 'gerund-participle'), and their function is that of **predicator** (or *head*) of the clauses that contain them.

It's a fairly complex construction. There may be some ambiguity, but the most salient analysis is:

The matrix verb is "was", and the two elements in emboldened brackets form a coordination of clauses functioning jointly as complement of "was". The second coordinate clause contains the embedded clause "reading a story", which modifies "sister".

Incidentally, "Allice" is a girl's name, so shouldn't it be "her sister", not "his sister"? Or are you referring to someones else's sister?

Answer (score 0):

The part of speech for all of them is *present participle*.

They are all part of the *past continuous*, which, in this case, has the function of describing an ongoing event in the past at the same time as another event, or at a specific time. Without more context, it's impossible to say for sure why past continuous was used here.